# How to convert Windows 7 partitions to qcow2?

Tags: virtualization, window, qemu

I know I can use `qemu-img` tool to convert a raw partition into a image file. But Windows 7 has two partitions. I tried:

```
qemu-img convert /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2 win7.qcow2
```

But the generated file does not have the correct partition infomation, thus cannot work. I also tried converting only the *System* partition and let the Windows 7 installation program to fix it for me, and the program says it cannot fix it ;(

I then used the [disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415) utility to create VHD image, then tried to convert it into qcow2, but qemu-img returned error:

```
File too large.
```

The generated VHD image file is about 15GB. **The file system I am working on is ext4.** So I do not think it is a file system limit issue.

Comment: Are you trying to store your file on a FAT32 filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should do this in two steps:

**First**:
Make an LV as raw disk, built a partition table there with entries that correspond to sda1 and sda2.

Make these partitions available: `kpartx -av /dev/VG/LV`

Use `dd` (propably with bs=1m) to copy sda1 to the first and sda2 to the second "partition".

Now you should have a raw-disk-image that corresponds to your physical windows partitions.

Try to use that LV as disk (sas, sata or scsi emulation).

If that works your **second** step is to convert the LV to a different container format.

Comment: have not tried. sounds would work. thanks ;)